# Can't catch all the events using ethers

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, events

Can't catch all the events. Why?

I try to listen to events for several contracts and it is ok. But the more contracts I listen to, the more events are missed? Is there any way to prevent this and why event listening does not work correctly when I want to listen to, for example, 100 contracts at once. Are there any guidelines how to do it correctly ?

Such a trivial question. Maybe I should just listen to one contract for each file, only it seems a bit punitive....

My code looks like most tutorials and so it starts like this:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contract,  abi , provider )
    //  contract.on("Transfer", async (from, to, value, event, error) => {  
      ///test
```

I tried both ethers js and web3. In both cases, when I listen to more events in one file, more often the event is not recorded, and I want to make sure that it captures 100% of the events

Answer (score 0):

When I have needed to listen to events in the past, I don’t need to instantiate the contract each time like this.

To be clear, im not sure why the method you’re using doesn’t work consistently - perhaps you could post some code to help us get through this.

Usually I would use Alchemy or Infura to open a web socket or use `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters()` and pass the necessary types array needed to decode the event topic handlers. The code might look something like this in JS:

```
typesArray = 
[{
    type: 'address',
    name: 'addressFromTopic',
    indexed: true
}];

for (log of logs) {   
   try {
let logData = {
address: web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(topicArray,String(log.topics[1]);
}  catch { error }};
```

…for instance if you were trying to decode the first topic (perhaps the event emit from the contract) of the transaction on chain. This will give 100% yield as long as you define your `to` address properly in the `decodeParameters()` call, and any failed log reads can be noted and re-run in the `catch` block (yes, server timeout errors et al are quite common)

Hope that helps

Comment: Can I do the same thing using ANKR ? I still don't know what I am doing wrong .  I tried web3 but I'm better off with ethers js - I think the problem is that I'm using the for each function and there's just too much of it in one file - but why??  items.forEach(function(name) {
 
 




     const contract = new ethers.Contract(name.contract, name.abi , name.provider )
    //  contract.on("Transfer", async (from, to, value, event, error) => {  
 

      contract.on("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", async (from, to, value, event, error) => {